# When i go to load in a a Minecraft world to test if block generation is working properly i get this error message

Tags: java, minecraft

```
RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
```

here is the full crash report if needed-

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

```
// Who set us up the TNT?

Time: 7/17/16 9:41 AM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
    at hunterghostfist.supersodas.YeastGeneration.generateOre(YeastGeneration.java:50)
    at hunterghostfist.supersodas.YeastGeneration.generateOverworld(YeastGeneration.java:35)
    at hunterghostfist.supersodas.YeastGeneration.generate(YeastGeneration.java:22)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.generateWorld(GameRegistry.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.populate(ChunkProviderServer.java:314)
    at net.minecraft.world.chunk.Chunk.populateChunk(Chunk.java:1157)
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.originalLoadChunk(ChunkProviderServer.java:208)
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.loadChunk(ChunkProviderServer.java:149)
    at net.minecraft.world.gen.ChunkProviderServer.loadChunk(ChunkProviderServer.java:119)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.initialWorldChunkLoad(MinecraftServer.java:305)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.loadAllWorlds(IntegratedServer.java:79)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.startServer(IntegratedServer.java:96)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:445)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$2.run(MinecraftServer.java:752)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

-- System Details --

```
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_91, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 832797088 bytes (794 MB) / 1038876672 bytes (990 MB) up to 1038876672 bytes (990 MB)
JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95
FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.99.99 Minecraft Forge 10.13.4.1614 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
UCHIJAA     mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar)
UCHIJAA     FML{7.10.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar)
UCHIJAA     Forge{10.13.4.1614} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar)
UCHIJAA     ss{ 1.0} [Super Sodas] (bin)
GL info: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 8; []
Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
```

Comment: You should provide more details about what you are doing. The answer of @Peter Lawrey is the most specific you can get with the information you're currently providing.

Answer (score 1):

This tells you all you need to know

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
at     java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
at     hunterghostfist.supersodas.YeastGeneration.generateOre(YeastGeneration.java:50)
```

This means on this line `YeastGeneration.generateOre(YeastGeneration.java:50)` you are calling `Random.nextInt(x)` but the value you are passing is not positive and it must be. e.g. you are passing 0 or a negative number

Comment: @HunterPowell you can accept the answer if you find it useful.